# how to send multiple telegram polls with a bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

So i wanted to send three different telegram polls using it's bot API. This is the code i have so far.

```
import requests
import json
base_url = "https://api.telegram.org/.../sendPoll(3)"
parameters = {
    "chat_id": ,
    "question": ,
    "options": json.dumps([]),
    "allows_multiple_answers": True,
    "public_voters": True,
}
resp = requests.get(base_url, data=parameters)
print(resp.text)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need bot token to add in the `base_url`

Comment: yes i know i just haven't shared it here for privacy reasons

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Just call print 3 times with different parameters.

Like this:

```
print(resp1.text)
resp2 = requests.get(base_url, data=parameters2)
print(resp2.text)
resp3 = requests.get(base_url, data=parameters3)
print(resp3.text)
```

Comment: With different…? Can you [edit] your question to clarify what you mean?